# passing parameters into MySQL routine

Tags: mysql

I want to do something like this with MySQL routines

```
PROCEDURE `abc`(t1 varchar(50), t2 varchar(50))
BEGIN

    DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
       SELECT * FROM t2

    CREATE TABLE t2 SELECT * FROM t1;

    OPEN...FETCH...CLOSE CURSOR

END
```

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE GetOfficeByCountry(IN countryName VARCHAR(255))
    BEGIN
        SELECT city, phone 
        FROM countryName
        WHERE country = "uk";
    END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Here is an example i found